cloud.session.token for Trello API
I use Postman to test working with the API, everything works, but I don’t understand how to transfer it to python. Since I don’t understand where Postman generates
Cookie: cloud.session.token=eyJraWQiOiJzZXNzaW9uLXNlcnZpY2UvcHJvZC0xNTkyODU4Mzk0IiwiYWxnIjoiUlMyNTYifQ..f4hRGErlJHXs9ISp_iLJeD135fJk8qkZtaU20claG1uNjUhy7kDBgq-hfP5VjTmeKDNcWj6GPPbKXmrs-SOpHb3dsmTDqD_D1KWpp-w0Vu2nPfi38liJ4HiiIyo8onwhwEv-YurBhN0X1_smcTRvyp7lr5BTEjqglnh5fWy_sQlKkA3tlZN5rPLFKl4C6lVB2wCDduVMPWwbQxPZBuFxwJYTYOtbGiSt7SM87qSIu_S7amVBaZZPNdcvFDmUraB8X_Mil2n9hSoYnMOBqrJ263M0NGWJJWK2FMslVuFY9q-0MS-rbwTaG_t8Tc4yKghI2U34HY0754sjET7


when I pass these cookies in headers to Python, the code works. but how would I be able to get these cookies on every request? or are they always the same?
the cookie string itself is more like a token

Postman did not "generate" this cookie, it must have received it in response to a previous request.

@C3roe This is the only request I make. I am not passing a cookie variable to this request

Then show some more details of what you are actually doing, please.

I send a GET request using this link. https://trello.com/1/cards/API-key/attachments/secret-key/download/resized_photo_4.jpg. and I get the image. I wrote a code in python with downloading an image. it only works with the cookie header. But are these cookies created over time or not because they are a bit like a token @C3roe

Can't test it myself with that URL, cause it only gives an error response (due to no actual API key, I suppose) - but perhaps this URL performs a redirect? And sets a the cookie in that process? So that you might be thinking you made only one single request in postman, but actually it is more than that ...?

@C3roe I opened the query console in postman and there was also 1 query there

Is there any way we can test this? (Not sure if the API key can be exposed to 3rd parties.)

@C3roe I would send you this link, but my reputation is not enough for personal chats

What happens when you request that same URL in a private tab in your browser (where no cookies should exist upfront)? Do you get the expected result? If not, are you getting redirected anywhere else?

@C3roe Wow! yes, it asks me to log in
